# drawing a barcode with turtle graphics on python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I know that there are crazy short cuts to doing a lot of things with Python, which is where I'm running into trouble with this project for my intro CIS class. I've searched for variations of my question, but without luck.. SO:

the project is to make our "turtle" draw a barcode using a ZIP that would be entered into the command line. I have a lot of the structural work done, ie: encodings for specific digits and telling the turtle how long to draw the bars for specific digits.. however, now I'm stuck at writing the for loops to actually put those two pieces together and get the program drawing the barcode.

here's what I have:

```
import argparse # Used in main program to obtain 5-digit ZIP code from command
            # line
import time # Used in main program to pause program before exit
import turtle   # Used in your function to print the bar code

## Constants used by this program
SLEEP_TIME = 30 # number of seconds to sleep after drawing the barcode
ENCODINGS = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],   # encoding for '0'
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],   # encoding for '1'
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],   # encoding for '2'
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],   # encoding for '3'
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],   # encoding for '4'
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],   # encoding for '5'
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],   # encoding for '6'
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],   # encoding for '7'
         [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],   # encoding for '8'
         [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]    # encoding for '9'
        ]
SINGLE_LENGTH = 25  # length of a short bar, long bar is twice as long

def compute_check_digit(digits):

    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(digits)):
        sum = sum + digits[i]
    check_digit = 10 - (sum % 10)
    if (check_digit == 10):
        check_digit = 0
    return check_digit


def draw_bar(my_turtle, digit):
    my_turtle.left(90)
    if digit == 0:
        length = SINGLE_LENGTH
    else:
        length = 2 * SINGLE_LENGTH
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.up()
    my_turtle.backward(length)
    my_turtle.right(90)
    my_turtle.forward(10)
    my_turtle.down()


def draw_zip(my_turtle, zip):
    # WHAT DO I DO 
    print("My code to draw the barcode needs to replace this print statement")

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("ZIP", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    zip = args.ZIP
    if zip <= 0 or zip > 99999:
        print("zip must be > 0 and < 100000; you provided", zip)
    else:
        my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        draw_zip(my_turtle, zip)
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The argparse/parser stuff at the beginning and end is given to us when we start each project.

I know this next line would be helpful somewhere, i looked up the map feature and i know that i need to convert the encodings to integers from strings.

map(list, str(zip))

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please remember to read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be of particular help here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the digits of the zip.
For each digit, you iterate through the 5 bars.

```
for str_digit in str(zip):
    digit = int(str_digit)
    for bar_bit in ENCODINGS[digit]:
        draw_bar(my_turtle, bar_bit)
        <move turtle to next bar's starting point>
```

I hope this is understandable to you.  You can shorten the code with various Python techniques, but this is easy to understand.

Comment: Prune... you rock! makes total sense. With all of the extra stuff given to us in the beginning/end its a little overwhelming for a novice programmer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help.  Most of what you do will involve two types of decomposition: (1) Breaking a long task into shorter tasks to do in order: step A, step B, step C, etc.  (2) Breaking a repetitive job into a "do it once" loop body and a "how to repeat" wrapper (which often includes a couple of lines of set-up and after-work).

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. thanks for your help.. i got a pretty good grade on this project thanks to you :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  This is worth far more than reputation points.

Comment: BTW, do remember to "accept" an answer, so StackOverflow can properly retire the question.